# What is the most pythonic way to deal with a conditional statement that may raise an error?

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to deal with a conditional statement that may raise an error? For example:

```
if string[0] = "#":
```

The above statement will result in an IndexError if given a string with a length of 0.

I imagine something that looks like this:

```
if try testFunction() (except: pass):
```

...but I know that wouldn't work. So what should I do?

NOTE: There are many solutions to this problem. For example, I could put the if statement inside a second if statement... but this wouldn't be elegant. I'm specifically looking for the most pythonic solution.

Comment: `if string[0] = "#":` Actually, it will result in a SyntaxError.

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to put the *whole `if` statement* in a `try..except` block:

```
try:
    if string[0] == "#":
        # block executed when true
except IndexError:
    # ..
```

There are are better alternatives however:

- extract that one character first:

  ```
  try:
      first = string[0]
  except IndexError:
      pass
  else:
      if first == '#':
          # ...
  ```
- test for the string length first:

  ```
  if string and string[0] == '#':
  ```
- use slicing:

  ```
  if string[:1] == '#':
  ```

  slicing results in an empty string if `string` is empty to start with.
- use a string method:

  ```
  if string.startswith('#'):
  ```